# MySql Order by Field last uploaded get first in front of ordered id's

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order some datas and use ORDER BY FIELD. The order for the given id's looks well, but when i add another record in database this record just get in front of the ordered id's datas. When i add another record i want that record to be the last after the ordered ones. The code i use is below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM echipa ORDER BY FIELD(id_profesor, 14,17,16,24,25,22,26,19,20,21,18,23)');
```

Comment: why not add a date field `created_at` ?

Comment: or at least a field specifically for ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `if` statement in the `order by`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM echipa 
ORDER BY IF(FIELD(id_profesor, 14,17,16,24,25,22,26,19,20,21,18,23)=0,1,0),
    FIELD(id_profesor, 14,17,16,24,25,22,26,19,20,21,18,23)
```

The problem is `field` returns 0 for non matching records, which would return at the top of the list.  This forces records not found to the bottom.

Comment: can't be very efficient, do you know how the indexes are handled in such a case?

Comment: @Dagon -- I don't personally use `field` very often (if ever) -- this is just 1 way of forcing such an order with this particular design.  If performance is an issue, perhaps restructuring the table would make more sense.

Comment: @Dagon . . . Indexes are not going to be used for this sort anyway, so that really isn't a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

One solution where you don't have to repeat the expression is to convert the 0 to a `NULL` and then the `NULL` to something else:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(FIELD(id_profesor, 14,17,16,24,25,22,26,19,20,21,18,23), 0), 9999)
```

Another is to use the fact that a descending sort puts `NULL`s last:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id_profesor, 14,17,16,24,25,22,26,19,20,21,18,23) DESC
```

However, you might want to reverse the order of the list to keep the rows in the original order.

Or, if you really want to be fancy, you can do something like this:

```
ORDER BY - NULLIF(FIELD(id_profesor, 14,17,16,24,25,22,26,19,20,21,18,23), 0) DESC
```

I would consider the intention rather inscrutable in this case.